# Различное форматирование HTML-разметки при предпросмотре и конечном результате

Tags: дефект, сниппеты

[**Ответ**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/613468/199934), проблемный кусок кода:

```html
        <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        От колумеллы завернул на срисованный с топографической карты мост греческого носа, разогнался и очутился перед ширью чела, усеянной едва приметными эфемеридами. Отдельно торчащие волоски обрамляли пушистый каскад, вуалью из тончайшей паутинки прикрывая внитие в пробор посередине. Нежная кожа руки, несомненно, ароматнее цветов на иконах ниже... Тщательно протёр зенки: стоп, я не Виктор Кандинский во власти дебютной галлюцинации.
        <br><br>
        Однако стоило попутчице с ближнего ко входу сидения подвинуть локоть, как проступили пухленькие губки, слабо напоминающие Божьи. Они принадлежали высокой мощной путешественнице с неуклюжей широкой походкой, непринуждённо закинувшей наверх свой и подруги громадные рюкзаки. Помимо профиля с закрытыми очами в ней не содержалось ни на йоту от Эталона, чего, правда, вполне хватало для любования. Тут осенило, как провести эту обездвиживающую и притупляющую ночь.
    </body>
```

**Результат при предпросмотре:** (можно увидеть, кликнув на `править`)

[image: Предпросмотр]

**Результат в ответе:**

[image: Ответ]

Тег `<head>` расположен в различных местах.

я форматирую код, ориентируясь на то, что вижу при предпросмотре, но после того, как ответ дан, визуально результат получается иным.

- Браузеры Firefox 50.0.1, включая [**Safe Mode**](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-firefox-issues-using-safe-mode), и Chrome 55.0.2883.87 m;
- Проблема воспроизводится [**в Песочнице**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/289714/326972).

Comment: попробуй не использовать контейнеры head и body

Comment: @Grundy, но если в примере они будут нужны. Лучше ведь демонстрировать реальный код, а не так, что в сниппете один — на практике другой. Спасибо.

Comment: сниппет по дефолту вставляет все в боди и если в коде стоят такие теги как  html/head/body ему могут потребоваться дополнительные движения. Поэтому стоит определить влияют ли они на эту ситуацию или нет

Comment: @Grundy, ясно, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Похоже, что визуализатор сниппета игнорирует дополнительные пробелы в первой строке. Это похоже на здравый смысл: html-код всегда будет начинаться с какого-то корневого элемента, иначе он не будет валиден.

Попробовал открыть все сниппеты в режиме редактирования и нажать «вставить код» — лишние отступы автоматически исправились. Т.е. в логике сниппета даже есть автопочинка отступов.

Т.е. некоторое расхождение в поведении есть, но оно проявляется только если вы хотите опубликовать неправильно отформатированный код.

Comment: Nick Volynkin, я пишу ответы во внешнем редакторе, по окончании же написания форматирую их. Первоначально в ответе был [**вот этот код**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/289717/326972). Результат [**при предпросмотре**](http://i.imgur.com/Droq4Za.png) — [**в ответе**](http://i.imgur.com/DD19HwN.png). То же различие, хотя разметка отформатирована. Спасибо.